# How to scale a image in Android to a particular height and width with animation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, objectanimator

I want to animate an imageView to a particulate size (hight and width of another imageView). I thought it's easy but I could not found any proper solution.

What I have tried:

```
ObjectAnimator scaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img1, "scaleX", (float) img2.getWidth());
ObjectAnimator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img1, "scaleY", (float) img2.getHeight());
scaleX.setDuration(2000);
scaleY.setDuration(2000);
AnimatorSet scale = new AnimatorSet();
scale.play(scaleX).with(scaleY);
scale.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.0f, 1.0f);
    valueAnimator.setDuration(2000);
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            float scale = Float.parseFloat(animation.getAnimatedValue().toString());
            img2.setScaleX(scale);
            img2.setScaleY(scale);
        }
    });
    valueAnimator.start();
```

You don't need an object animator. You can use valueanimator to animate objects.

Don't forget to set pivot to your view before animating. Pivot should be the center coordinate "x,y" of your view.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) :

```
img1.animate().scaleX(toX).scaleY(toY).setDuration(2000);
```

or

```
img1.animate().scaleXBy(byX).scaleYBy(byY).setDuration(2000);
```

Alternately you could use a [ScaleAnimation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation.html).
Heres a short example with the shortest constructor:

```
ScaleAnimation sa = new ScaleAnimation(fromX , toX , fromY , toY);
sa.setDuration(2000);
img1.startAnimation(sa);
```

But I would recommend the first, because it's less code and a ScaleAnimation only moves the pixels on the screen so it is not really scaled, it just looks like it, while ViewPropertyAnimator really scales the View.